# Is it possible to create multiple queues in Kafka if so how multiple topics can be handled?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I would like to know to create the multiple queues/topics in apache kafka if it supports?

Comment: what do you mean by the queue? Definitely, Kafka employes many queues internally

Comment: @Srinivas Yarra : Kafka has topic [Publish-subscribe model], not queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create as many topics as you like... The are Kafka production deployments with many hundreds of topics. And because Kafka is distributed, you can always scale out you cluster if you need more capacity.